# My class component dispatch my action to reducer,but it show NULL array in store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm new learner in reacr-redux,I used react-reduct in my porject,
and some thing wrong ,the problem is what topic expound on,
after, I use function component with the same action and reducer,
it can work on useSelcect and useDispatch,so I think action and reducer is fine,
**but I can't understand what happended in class component!**

**here are my code**:

```
import { toHaveDisplayValue } from "@testing-library/jest-dom/dist/matchers";
import React from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createPlayerCard} from '../action';

class Test extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        let testArr=[1,2,3,4,5]
        createPlayerCard(testArr);

        console.log(this.props.playerCard?this.props.playerCard:"dont find playcard");
    }



    render(){
        return(
            <div></div>
            )
        
    }
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
    playerCard:state.playerCard
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{createPlayerCard})(Test)
```

**My action of createPlayerCard:**

```
export const createPlayerCard=(playerCard)=>({
    type:'PlayerCard',
    card:playerCard
});
```

**and the reducer of PlayerCard**:

```
const playerCardReducer=(state=[],action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'PlayerCard':
            return action.card;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**and the result:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLvJW.png)

I konw reducer dont recommand that using the same array ,
but I only use createPlayerCard one time to initial the card,and when I use dipsath in function component,it could work,I think the problem is not here,
May someone could help me figure out what the problem is?
i will be grateful for yor help!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Player Card Action is the Props of the Test Component. You have to Call as

```
 componentDidMount(){
        let testArr=[1,2,3,4,5]
        this.props.createPlayerCard(testArr);
    }
```

Also In your CreatePlayer action you have to dispatch the types.. Right Now You are just returning the object..

```
export const createPlayerCard=(playerCard)=> async function (dispatch) {
 dispatch({
    type:'PlayerCard',
    card:playerCard
});
};
```